# store array data in mysql using codeigniter-3

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want to store array data in database(mysql) using codeigniter

```
$data['product_data'] = $this->Products_database_fe->get_by_id($id);
```

`$data` contains data which i have fetch from database.
Now `$data` which contain an array, and i want to store that array data in phpmyamin using codeigniter-3

Comment: Improved formatting.

Comment: You mean you want to store `$data` in your database?

Comment: The record which contain $data that i want store in database

Comment: You mean `$data` handles data's that you've fetched from database and insert again to database?

Comment: yes..exactly...

Comment: encode it like serialize(), base64 encode etc and then you can put it in a column in your database .